# exec: "docker-credential-desktop.exe": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I got this error during `docker build`:

```
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04                                                                                                                                                                   2.1s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error getting credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-desktop.exe": executable file not found in $PATH, out: ``
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'build-local' failed
make: *** [build-local] Error 1
```

Answer (score 404, accepted):

This discussion solved my error:
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-credential-desktop-exe-executable-file-not-found-in-path-using-wsl2/100225

Delete the line with `credsStore` from `~/.docker/config.json`.

Or rename `credsStore` to  `credStore`

Comment: No clear answer on why does this work and what could be a better way to solve this. This one seems like a hack.

Comment: feels more like a fix

Comment: weird, but this worked for me

Comment: This is no different than just deleting the line outright. docker is looking for `credsStore` not `credStore`, since it can't find it, it uses it's default -- there is no magic here.

Comment: Confirmed fixes the issue.

Comment: @birsingh Changing credsStore to credStore simply disables that functionality, docker will then run without credentials.

Comment: lol, worked for me.

Comment: Renaming the mentioned attribute works.

Comment: I had to shift from Docker Desktop to Rancher Desktop. With rancher Desktop I used dockerd & started facing this issue. But this change resolved it well.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi is correct - the documentation is here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Comment: Worked for me... but isn't the whole point of Docker not having to rely on env-dependent configs in additional to the standard commands.

Comment: I got this error on macOS after uninstalling Docker Desktop (formerly Docker for Mac) and switching to just "normal" Docker (`brew install docker`).  It looks like the config was left pointing to Docker Desktop for credentials storage.  This answer solved it for me as well.

Comment: Funnily I had never installed Docker Desktop on my Mac (M1, MacOS 13.5+), but only installed `brew install colima docker docker-compose docker-buildx`, yet the `~/.docker/config.json` had sad wrong line (`"credsStore": "desktop"`) in it. Removing it and trying to log in into my private Docker registry worked afterwards. Before I seemed to be successfully logged-in, but since it could not store the credentials, there was an issue.

Comment: Not sure how this works, but it has been a really good solution for my trouble.

Comment: It worked. I wonder why...

Comment: can confirm. it worked for me on wsl with windows 11 without docker desktop.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 user here, deleting the credsStore parameter worked for me

Answer (score 80):

1. Just goto config `sudo vi ~/.docker/config.json`
2. rename `credsStore` to `credStore` and save.
   This actually fixed mine (arch).

Answer (score 25):

For me this happened when my org had to switch from docker desktop to colima, so here's detail from owner of colima:
https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/issues/52#issuecomment-956037291

```
───────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: ~/.docker/config.json
───────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ {
   2   │     "credsStore": "desktop".  <----- Delete this line
   3   │ }
───────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

You can delete that line and it should work fine.

Comment: That should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

Short answer: Delete the line with `credStore` from `~/.docker/config.json`.

Long explanation:

The property `credsStore` specifies an external binary to serve as the default credential store. When this property is set, `docker login` will attempt to store credentials in the binary specified by `docker-credential-<value>` which is visible on `$PATH`. If this property is not set, credentials will be stored in the auths property of the config.

Read more about it `https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#credential-store-options`.

Credits to @Javier Buzzi, vote up his comment as well.

Answer (score 7):

For Arch Linux edit the ~/.docker/config.json file and paste this code

```
{
    "auths": {},
    "credStore": "desktop",
    "currentContext": "default"
}
```

basically change `credsStore` to `credStore`

Answer (score 5):

today installed and removed docker desktop which is destroyed docker engine, right answer already given:

Delete the line with credsStore from ~/.docker/config.json

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed it on Mac with this:

sudo vim ~/.docker/config.json

rename "credsStore" to "credStore"

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this file `docker-credential-desktop` was not found because I was running only docker-engine.

To get this file, I had to install the docker-desktop user interface app, and from the docker-desktop, I logged in to my docker hub account. That's how it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, after editing the `credsStore` line in `~/.docker/config.json`, everything works fine. However, in reality, it's equally valid to either delete this line or modify it. In other words, you can change it to `credxxxxxxStore`, as long as the original `credsStore` doesn't exist.
Perhaps it's related to [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11261) .
[Windows 11, WSL2, Docker Desktop 4.28.0]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. When I logged into Docker Desktop I saw there was an update [to version 4.27.2] and applied it.

Then I tried building again and it worked.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me i had a different problem.
I always used the sudo comand for docker and changed the permissions by adding it to the docker group, logged out and than logged in again and it worked.
This is the link i followed:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem on Ubuntu 22 removing the line with credStore at ~/.docker/config.json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).